# Unable to get the associated model values through serializers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization

I am trying to fetch associated model values using serializers and everything seems fine but the associated model values are not showing up on the client side is there are any helpers in rails I can use?

Comment: Can you please add your serializer file here ?

Comment: can you mention the serializer used and the associations that you have mentioned?